# Is sum of subsets a subspace (or just a $\text{subset}$)?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $U,W\subset V$, where $V$ is a vector space, s $U+W$ a vector subspace of $V$? Note that only say "subset"

Comment: What or who says "subset"? And anyway: the sum of subspaces is always a subspace. Now, sum of **subsets** clearly is not, in general, a subspace.

Comment: I'm going to refer to @DonAntonio 's comment. Not every set is a vector space. Vector space is a specific algebraic structure consisting of a set and addition and scalar multiplication, i.e., a set is said to be a vector space if it's closed under addition and scalar multiplication, i.e., if it contains every linear combination of its elements(vectors).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with "subset" is that there might not be a concept of the zero vector in $U + W$. For example: we know that $V = \mathbb R$ is a vector space. If $U = \{2\}$ and $W = \{3\}$, then $U + W = \{5\}$, but $U+W$ is not a vector space because there is no zero vector. In fact, it's not closed under addition: We have $5\in U+W$, but $$5+5 = 10\not\in U+W.$$

Comment: I think the OP is also mixing the two terms: $\color{red}{\text{sum}}$ and $\color{red}{\text{union}}$ which is just a conaequence of a prior confusion explained in you answer.